# How can i use if condition in "create_query" in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In my form builder i am trying to use this

```
'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                                 return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                                 if(var)                                     
                                  ->where('u.id = 3')
```

Comment: Can you be more specific here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
    $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('u');

    if ($someCondition) {
        $qb->where('u.id = 3');
    }

    return $qb;
}
```